# GitLab not able to activate gitlab-kas

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

After installing the self-managed gitlab docker container, I'm facing an issue when trying to init a GitLab Kubernetes Agent.

First of all, I've added the `.gitlab/agents/<agent-name>/config.yaml` according to gitlab docs and it's possible to click the green **integrate with GitLab Agent** button, but then the dropdown is empty and the console returns an *500 internal server error* without any interesting information.

[image: Empty dropdown]

The **gitlab-kas** configuration in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` was enabled by default with those configuration:

```
##! Settings used by the GitLab application                                                            
# gitlab_rails['gitlab_kas_enabled'] = true
# gitlab_rails['gitlab_kas_external_url'] = ws://gitlab.example.com/-/kubernetes-agent
# gitlab_rails['gitlab_kas_internal_url'] = grpc://localhost:8153
                                                                         
##! Enable GitLab KAS                       
# gitlab_kas['enable'] = true
```

Last but not least, found some more helpful logs in `docker logs -f gitlab` I guess:

```
Gitlab::Kas::Client::ConfigurationError (GitLab KAS is not enabled):
  lib/gitlab/kas/client.rb:16:in `initialize'
  ee/app/graphql/resolvers/kas/agent_configurations_resolver.rb:28:in `new'
  ee/app/graphql/resolvers/kas/agent_configurations_resolver.rb:28:in `kas_client'
  ee/app/graphql/resolvers/kas/agent_configurations_resolver.rb:16:in `resolve'
  lib/gitlab/graphql/present/field_extension.rb:18:in `resolve'
  lib/gitlab/graphql/generic_tracing.rb:40:in `with_labkit_tracing'
  lib/gitlab/graphql/generic_tracing.rb:30:in `platform_trace'
  lib/gitlab/graphql/generic_tracing.rb:40:in `with_labkit_tracing'
  lib/gitlab/graphql/generic_tracing.rb:30:in `platform_trace'
  lib/gitlab/graphql/generic_tracing.rb:40:in `with_labkit_tracing'
  lib/gitlab/graphql/generic_tracing.rb:30:in `platform_trace'
  app/graphql/gitlab_schema.rb:40:in `multiplex'
  ...
```

So it seams that the **gitlab-kas** service is not running, but how can I boot it up?

Answer (score 2):

OMG **ID10T** incoming: after studying the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` config again, I found the error and it's kind of obvious. Changed settings is good, but if they were not included, it doesn't help at all.

In reference to the original question, within the provided config screenshot you can see, that the setting is actually a comment. After removing the `#` it works fine.